# unix - max(length) of each column in file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

Given a file with data like this (ie stores.dat file)

```
sid|storeNo|latitude|longitude
2tt|1|-28.0372000t0|153.42921670
9|2t|-33tt.85t09t0000|15t1.03274200
```

Desired output:

```
sid : 3
storeNo : 2
latitude : 16
longitude : 13
```

What is the syntax to return the maximum length of the values under each column?

I have tried this but it does not work:

```
nawk 'BEGIN { FS = "|" }
{
for(n = 1; n <= NF; n++) {
if (length($n) > max)
max = length($n)
maxlen[$n] = max
}
}
END {
for (i in maxlen) print "col " i ": " maxlen[i]
} ' stores.dat
```

UPDATE (thanks to Mat's answer - I settled on this):

```
awk -F"|" '  NR==1{
    for(n = 1; n <= NF; n++) {
       colname[n]=$n
    }
}
NR>1{
    for(n = 1; n <= NF; n++) {
        if (length($n)>maxlen[n])
            maxlen[n]=length($n)
    }
}
END {
        for (i in colname) {
                print colname[i], ":", maxlen[i]+0;
        }
} ' filename
```

Comment: When something doesn't work, you should give not just your desired output (which you provided), but also the actual output that your sample code gives.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a few problems with your script - `max` is shared between columns, and you're not dealing with the header line at all. Try the following:

```
$ cat t.awk 
#!/bin/awk -f
NR==1{
    for(n = 1; n <= NF; n++) {
       colname[n]=$n
    }
}
NR>1{
    for(n = 1; n <= NF; n++) {
        if (length($n)>maxlen[n])
            maxlen[n]=length($n)
    }
}
END {
        for (i in maxlen) {
                print colname[i], ":", maxlen[i];
        }
}
$ awk -F'|' -f t.awk stores.dat
```

`$n` refers to the contents of the `n`th column. `n` is the column number (in the first and second loop). The last loop just shows a way of iterating over an array in `awk`.

Comment: `$n`: contents of column `n` in the current line. `n` is just a number.

Comment: This gives me 10 errors such as- awk: syntax error near line 2   awk: illegal statement near line 2  awk: bailing out near line 6. I'm using SunOS if that helps.

Comment: @toop: try to see if you have `gawk` installed.

Comment: unfortunately, no gawk installed

Comment: @toop: just tried it on Solaris 10 and it works as expected (with awk and nawk)

Comment: @toop If you are getting errors at line 2, then it looks like you haven't edited the script to use `#!/bin/nawk -f` instead of `#!/bin/awk -f`, though I may be wrong here.

Comment: I see, if `n` is `2`, then `$n` refers to `$2`.

Answer (score 0):

My take on this is by using a pure Bash approach:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

dat=./stores.dat
del='|'
TOKENS=$(head -1 "${dat}" | tr $del ' ')
declare -a col=( $TOKENS )
declare -a max

skip=1
while IFS=$del read $TOKENS; do
    if [ $skip -eq 1 ]; then
        skip=0
        continue
    fi
    idx=0
    for tok in ${TOKENS}; do
        tokref=${!tok}
        printf "%-10s = %-16s[%2d] " "$tok" "${tokref}" "${#tokref}"
        echo "--> max=${max[$idx]} tokref=${#tokref}"
        #This works  : c=$a>$b?$a:$b
        #This doesn't: max[$idx]=${max[$idx]}>${#tokref}?${max[$idx]}:${#tokref}
        max[$idx]=$((${max[$idx]:=0}>${#tokref}?${max[$idx]}:${#tokref}))
        let idx++
    done
    printf "\n"
done < ${dat}

for ((idx=0; idx<${#col[@]}; idx++)); do
    printf "%-10s : %d\n" "${col[$idx]}" "${max[$idx]}"
done
```

The output is as follows:

```
sid        = 2tt             [ 3] --> max=0 tokref=3
storeNo    = 1               [ 1] --> max=0 tokref=1
latitude   = -28.0372000t0   [13] --> max=0 tokref=13
longitude  = 153.42921670    [12] --> max=0 tokref=12

sid        = 9               [ 1] --> max=3 tokref=1
storeNo    = 2t              [ 2] --> max=1 tokref=2
latitude   = -33tt.85t09t0000[16] --> max=13 tokref=16
longitude  = 15t1.03274200   [13] --> max=12 tokref=13

sid        : 3
storeNo    : 2
latitude   : 16
longitude  : 13
```

I've added this solution because I liked the challenge and had some minutes to spare.